# gave the wrong resignation notice period

Tags: resignation

I was having some difficulties at work where I have been for 8.5 years so I asked the secretary how much notice period I need to get and she told me 2 weeks.
Things deteriorated shortly after so I gave 2 weeks notice as per conversation. I worked those 2 weeks and the last day my employer told me I had given the wrong notice period, I then said I will work the extra 2 weeks then but was told to leave and they have refused to pay my pro rata.
I was under the impression that the employer should have informed me off the correct notice period?

Comment: You should be checking your work agreement, not asking a secretary. As for your question - it all depends on where you are and what local law applies

Comment: Please check your contract, it should tell you exactly what your required notice is.

Comment: Where is this located? You'll need to contact your Department of Labor (or equivalent) if you want to get back your stolen wages.

Comment: *You are not entitled to any payment other than those 2 weeks.*  You as the employee should also be aware, of the correct notice period you have to work.  If you are not aware, you end up working for 4 weeks, when the notice period is actually 2 weeks.

Answer (score 3):

When you give notice with a notice period, there are two possibilities:

Either the company has to accept the notice, due to the laws of your country and your contract. Then everything is clear, you leave after two weeks.

Or you gave a shorter notice. In that case, the company has two choices: Reject your notice (say you gave two weeks but you are required to give four, then they can reject your notice, so you give four weeks instead). Or accept your notice. They don't have to, but if they accept your notice, it is accepted.

In either case, you worked these two weeks, so they have to pay you for the weeks you worked. And they accepted your notice, so whether you gave the right or wrong notice doesn't matter anymore. They accepted it.

Probably best to tell them that they need to pay for the time you worked, or your lawyer will ask them to pay, which will make it only more costly for them.

But do I get this right: You gave two weeks notice, you worked two weeks, then some discussions, then you left. Except for the completely irrelevant "some discussions" you gave two weeks notice and they accepted two weeks notice.